# How to keep DRY while creating common controllers in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, dry

As I was working on my Laravel app, I noticed that I was creating controllers' methods which were very similar. For example, I have models: Task, Block, Lesson, etc. And in every controller there are very similar methods:

```
public function index()
{
    return new GeneralResource(/model/::all());
}

public function show(/model/ $model)
{
    return new GeneralResource($model);
}

public function store(/model/Request $request)
{
    try {
        $model = /model/::create($request->validated());
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function update(/model/Request $request, /model/ $model)
{
    try {
        $model->update($request->validated());
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function destroy(/model/ $model)
{
    try {
        $model->delete();
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Maybe I could extend Controller class with these methods and pass parameters as protected properties, but I am not sure how this can be done.

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Template Method. You can do it for each method from the controllers :)

More info:

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method/php/example
https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Behavioral/TemplateMethod/README.html